# Subscribing to a Websphere topic in Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty, spring-jms

I'm using Websphere Liberty and need to subscribe to a topic in Websphere Traditional.

I'm using spring messaging.  I was able to setup a sample app that uses the embedded JMS in websphere liberty to send and receive messages.  My problem comes in when trying to subscribe to a websphere traditional topic.  I'm not seeing any messages come in.

The documentation for this is very vague:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_msg_interop1.html#twlp_msg_interop1

It's not clear to me if the jndi name defined in the JMS Topic is supposed to match the jndi name in websphere traditional.  Also the topicName defined in properties.wasJms, should that be the jndi name or just the name?

I almost hesitate to mention this but it may help debug the problem.  If from in my app I use JmsTemplate to publish to the remote topic I get the message EVEN IF THE TOPIC ISN'T DEFINED in server.xml or in Websphere traditional.  I purposefully connected to FOOBAR as the topic name and subscribed to FOOBAR and I get the message. FOOBAR doesn't exist anywhere.....

I would have expected to see errors in the WAS Traditional server but I don't. My suspicion here is that the message isn't getting to WAS at all and it's acting like it's just embedded.

Here's the relevant sections of my server.xml:

```
     <wasJmsOutbound id="BootstrapSecureMessaging" useSSL="true">
        <sslOptions sslRef="CustomSslNewOptions" />
    </wasJmsOutbound>

<jmsTopicConnectionFactory jndiName="jndi/MyTest">
    <properties.wasJms
        userName="wasadmin"
        password="SohJdmkR"
    clientID="defaultID" 
    remoteServerAddress="someserver:7286:BootstrapSecureMessaging"
    busName="MY.De1.Bus"/>
</jmsTopicConnectionFactory>

<jmsTopic jndiName="jms/sometopic">
    <properties.wasJms 
      topicName="SomeWasTraditionalTopic" 
      deliveryMode="Application"
      timeToLive="500000"
      priority="1"
      readAhead="AsConnection" 
    />
</jmsTopic>
```